# Jquery load() error

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

When I do :

```
$("#main").load("list.html");
```

the code works fine, but when I do:

```
$.post("mycode.php")
  .done(function(data) {
    $("#main").load(data);
  })
```

and mycode.php is :

```
$data = file_get_contents("list.html");
echo $data;
```

I get: `myrootURL/%3C!DOCTYPE 404 not found`

I checked data returned from post request and it's exactly the content of list.html
Any help please

Comment: I think you give the wrong url reference from `mycode.php`.. check your file structure again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.post("mycode.php")
  .done(function(data) {
    $("#main").html(data); //<-html not load
  })
```